# paypal sandbox guest checkout

Tags: paypal, sandbox, checkout

Has anybody successfully tested paypal guest checkout in the sandbox for both accepted and rejected transactions?

I am able to successfully complete transactions for £501.00 but not £1001.00.

Message displayed stating:

> We're sorry. We can't complete your purchase at this time. Please
>   return to the merchant and choose another way to pay.

I have been informed by paypal that it is not possible to test rejected transactions?